# Can I use an excel template for all of my reports in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, xslt-grouping

Hi I have an excel template in .xslt format and we use the template for all of our reporting services. However, we have not used SSRS for reporting service. Is there a way we can use the excel template and load all our reporting data into the template instead of manually creating the report's header and footer, and the design every time we develop a report using SSRS?

I appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use a .xslt file to create a template in SSRS but you could create a report template in SSRS which uses report parts to keep things consistent in certain areas of your reports e.g. headers/footers.

Unfortunately SSRS does not have great support for templates/style and the only other solutions I have seen is by pulling style values from a database and using expressions throughout your reports.

Comment: Which means there is basically nothing I can do to export in an excel template?